# Are there any drawbacks using logical instead of integer arrays and values in arithmetic operations?

Tags: arrays, matlab

For operations involving integers, is a vector of logical values equivalent to a vector of integers taking appropriate values of 0 and 1?

Will I run into unexpected consequences if I make computations on or apply functions to logical objects instead of integer objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It really depends on the case, but as always in programming: **the explicit conversion of variables is better than implicitly!**

Here a simple example, where you could see a difference:

```
x = [0 1 0 1 0]      %// 0     1     0     1     0
y = logical(x)       %// 0     1     0     1     0

y(y) = 5             %// 0     1     0     1     0
x(y) = 5             %// 0     5     0     5     0
y(x) = 5             %// error
x(x) = 5             %// error
```

So when it comes to indexing the indexed variable on the left hand side of the assignment determines the type of the output. **So as long as you can ensure, that your output is always double, you shouldn't run into problems.**

Have a look at this more complex example:

```
z = double([0 0 0 0 0])
z(y) = x(y) + y(y)
```

the first summand is *double*, the second is *logical*. But as **they are part of an arithmetic operation both summands are treated *double*.** As `z` is *double* as well, the result is *double*.

```
z =

     0     2     0     2     0
```

---

Now consider the following:

```
z = logical([0 0 0 0 0])
z(y) = x(y) + y(y)
```

again the first summand is *double*, the second is *logical*. And again they  are treated *double*. But `z` is *logical*, so the actually *double* result is converted to *logical*.

```
z =

     0     1     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Commonly, but not always.

The biggest difference is that calls to `islogical` will return false for any numeric input -- this may be done in functions where you're passing an index array as input.

Indexing other arrays will work fine (see thewaywewalk's answer), but type checking may cause you issues.