# Why does Matlab returns double as result of logical multiplication?

Tags: matlab, logical-operators

Is it normal that Matlab returns a double as a result for a logical multiplication ?

```
A=[true false];
B=[false true];
class(A.*B)
```

output is

```
ans =
double
```

The best way I found is a cast : `logical(A.*B)`, but I do not feel it is clean.

Comment: Just use the [logical operators](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html), in this case `&` or `&&` depending on inputs. You don't need to create logical vectors by casting `1` and `0` either, instead use `true` and `false`. For instance `A = [true false]`, or `A = true(1, 2)`

Comment: thanks, I am going to edit my question to make it clearer

Comment: You should read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623378/are-there-any-drawbacks-using-logical-instead-of-integer-arrays-and-values-in-ar/32624114#32624114). You're mixing logical arrays with arithmetic operations, which works in many cases because Matlab does an internal typer conversion. However, there are cases where you will run into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many languages (including Matlab) the `boolean type` (called `logical` in Matlab) is not a numeric type, even if it has an underlying numeric type (just like every other type). It's underlying numeric type is nothing but a `byte` (`uint8` in Matlab) whose possible values are constrained to `0` and `1`.

In the majority of programming languages, when you try to perform arithmetic operations between booleans, the compiler throws an error telling you that it's not possible. Matlab, on the opposite, performs an implicit conversion of your `logicals` to `double` before proceeding with the calculations, and let you go on without errors:

```
A = [true false]; => A = [1 0];
B = [false true]; => A = [0 1];
ans = A .* B;

whos ans => double
```

That's why your result type is `double`.

Actually, if you want to perform operations with `logicals`, sticking to `logical` return type... you have to use logical operators. For more details: https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/logical-operations.html

Actually, your result can be achieved staying in the `logical` domain through:

```
res = A & B;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found ! It is simply `A&B`

```
>> A&B
ans =
     0     0

>> class(ans)
ans =
     logical
```